# placement new signature

Tags: c++

```
 void someCode()
 {
   char memory[sizeof(Foo)];     
   void* place = memory;          

   Foo* f = new(place) Foo();
 }
```

and the signature of new placement operator

```
void * operator new(size_t, void *p)
{
  return p;
}
```

I don't get how a constructor could be bind to void *p since a constructor doesn't return any values ?

**EDIT:**
the following code for instance doesn't compile :

```
struct A{};

void f(void * p)
{
}


int main()
{ 
    f(A());

  std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Why would the constructor have to return anything?

Comment: `operator new` only return memory bulk for object, constructor called _after_ operator new executed.

Comment: The constructor does return something. An instance of `Foo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that C++ `new` is confusing:

- there is the `operator new`, which you can overload and is in charge of allocating raw memory
- there is the `new` expression (such as `new A(5)`) which under the covers first call the corresponding `operator new` overload and *then* performs the construction

Note that you have no say as to how the construction is performed: you supplied the type and the constructor parameters, the language does the rest, and there is no way to change this behavior.

Therefore, when you overload/override `operator new`, you are only affecting the raw memory allocation. The full syntax of the `new` expression can clear things up:

```
new (somepointer) A(5)
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~
```

The first part is the list of arguments passed to `operator new`, *on top* of the size of the object (always passed). The second part corresponds to the constructor call. If there is no parameter to be passed to `new` (apart from the size which you don't control) then the first part may be omitted yielding the typical form `new A(5)`.

You are free to overload `new` as much as you want, for example:

```
new (alignof(A)) A(5);
```

will call an `operator new` overload accepting a `size_t` as supplementary argument (representing the necessary alignment for the type):

```
void* operator new(size_t size, size_t alignment);
```

*note: the first argument (size) is always there.*

So, placement new is just a fancy overload in its own right:

```
void* operator new(size_t, void* p) { return p; }
```

There is not much interest in such an operator (it does nothing), however it helps maintaining a consistent syntax and allows you a way to specify where to build an object via using the `new` expression so that it is not necessary to create another syntax to allow such operation.

Comment: The problem isn't that `new` is confusing, but that the OP is confused by `new`. The old Soviet Russia syndrome.

Answer (score 2):

Constructor called after operator new executed. You posted not equivalent code. Equvalent would be

```
struct A
{
    constructor (void* this);
}

int main ()
{
   A a = A::constructor(operator new ());
}
```

It is not `c++`, just pceudocode

Comment: can I call explicitly operator new in my code rather than new ?

Comment: You shouldn't. You wouldn't be able to call a constructor.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the source of your confusion is an assumption that `new(place) Foo();` is a single operation; it is not. Here is what's going on:

- A placement new operator is called to allocate memory
- A constructor is called to initialize the allocated memory

The first call needs to return the value (a `void*`). It is a block of memory suitable to store your object. The second call is a constructor. It gets the value from the placement new operator as its hidden `this` parameter, and performs its regular initialization tasks on it.

Comment: Ok I see, strange syntax by the way.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: nonsense: the placement new signature for objects is, indeed `operator new(size_t, void*)`. The one for array objects is `operator new[](size_t, void*)` (see 18.6 [support.dynamic] paragraph 1). In C++2011 you need to add `noexcept` to the declaration, though.

Comment: @DietmarKühl You are correct, I looked at the wrong line in the reference. It's been good 15 years since I used placement new, so I need to refresh my memory on a lot of things. Thanks!